# Triac substitute for BTA12 600TW?

Tags: transistors, solid-state-relay, triac

Can I safely use a Triac at a higher specification than designed? e.g. for a BTA12 600TW, could I safely use a BTA18 800TW i.e. where the volt & amp values are larger than the spec?Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, yes. You can use a Triac with a heavier rating in an application that was intended for a lower rating. Devices with heavier ratings are generally more expensive, that is why devices with lower ratings exist.

There may be some complications:

- Heavier devices may have larger parasitic capacitances.
- Heavier devices may have a different resistance.
- Obviously, the form-factor may be different.
- The turn-on current Ig may be different (higher).

However, in most applications this will not be a problem, especially when using devices from the same series, as you are suggesting.